# AJAX data Variable not Loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, jplayer

I have an AJAX statement that is meant to return echoed output from a PHP script the output is XML.

If navigate directly to the PHP script it outputs the JSON in the exact format I need.

the "data" variable in the AJAX request is not returning it properly, even though firebug network tab says status 200 ok for request.

The PHP returning XML elements "MP3 and Title"

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://www.startalkradio.net/?page_id=354';
    $rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
    $items = $rss->channel->item;

    $i = 0;
    $data = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $data[] = array(
            'title' => (string) $item->title,
            'mp3'   => (string) $item->enclosure['url'],
        );
        if (++$i == 3) break;
    }

    $jsdata = json_encode($data);
    echo htmlspecialchars($jsdata, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
?>
```

AJAX call populating JPlayer script. `data` does not seem to be returned.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get(
        "http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php", 
        function(data) {
            new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            }, 
            data, 
            {        <!-- here I am returning the php script to populate XML into JPlayer. -->
                swfPath: "js",
                supplied: "mp3, oga",
                wmode: "window"
            });
        }
    );
});
```

the [link](http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/player.html) in question

Here is a version that works note that the XML is the same as what is output by the PHP script 
[link](http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/player.php)

Comment: Have you tried to speicfy the datatype as XML? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ , 4th parameter is dataType. You could also switch to the $.ajax method so you can bind an error event. Also, you could console.log(data); inside of your function to see what the response was.

Comment: http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php is returning JSON not XML.

Comment: I should have spotted that it was JSON and not XML, If you're using JSON, make sure the dataType is set to JSON

Comment: ah yeah i have to rename that file, very misleading.

Comment: I am still showing undefined even with dataType set to JSON

Comment: i just viewed both your "player" pages - both appear to be working (in Chrome). Have you fixed it now? Or is it a particular browser that is failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you are returning XML but your PHP uses `json_encode()`. So your `$.get()` call should specify that:

```
//using `$.getJSON()` will set the dataType property to json so your server-side output will be parsed into a JavaScript object
$.getJSON(
        "http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php", 
        function(data) {
            console.log(data);//<--use this to inspect the JSON object returned from the server, make sure it's in the proper format
            new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
            }, 
            data, 
            {        <!-- here I am returning the php script to populate XML into JPlayer. -->
                swfPath: "js",
                supplied: "mp3, oga",
                wmode: "window"
            });
        }
    );
```

`data` should look something like this:

```
data = [
    {"title":"some title", "mp3":"path to some song"},
    {"title":"some other title", "mp3":"path to some other song"},
    etc...
];
```

Comment: The $.get method also allows the user to specify what format to expect "data" in. both $.getJSON and $.get will work as long as the dataType is specified when using $get